# Dissolve polygons based on number of polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, dissolve

How can I dissolve group of polygons into many polygons based on specific number?

For example I have 100 points which are beside each other I need to dissolve each nearest 5 polygons into 1.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Does the five polygons have some common attribute?

Comment: no common attribute,I need only to depend on spatial location.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ArcGIS Advanced license, you can use spatial sort existing in the [Sort tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm).

I found a similar answer from [here](https://community.esri.com/thread/195092-group-every-near-50-points-together?commentID=687372#comment-687293), so in the sorted point table put them into groups with the python expression which can be adjusted (every 5 points) to be like this:

```
int(OBJECTID / 5) + 1 # shapefile (OIDs start with 0)
```

You need to add a new column and name it `Count` of type integer and write the following expression using Field Calculator:

```
int( !FID! / 5) + 1
```

[image]

The you can dissolve your point file based on Count Field.

Personally, I don't have Advanced license to use spatial sort, but based on the link above it is recommended to use spatial sort of type PEANO.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,I have implemented the sort but how to put them in group using the python  expression .

Comment: @yazouri I updated my answer for more information.